# Alpha Testing Android game via Google Play

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am about to start a closed alpha test for my Android game, that uses Google Play Games.

As far as I have understood, I actually need to *publish* the game (with an alpha APK uploaded) to receive the correct link, and to start the alpha testing?

I am a bit concerned that I cannot change some things (like delete achievements) even after publishing a test version of my game... am I correct? Or does this apply only when I publish a production version of my game?

This is what the Google Play Games publish button says, even though I haven't uploaded a production APK (just the alpha APK):

**Please note that certain aspects of the game cannot be changed after publishing (all fields marked with a padlock) and that achievements cannot be deleted after publishing.
It might take a few hours until the functionality is available.**

Comment: *'As far as I have understood I actually need to publish the game (with an alpha APK uploaded) to receive the correct link, and to start the alpha testing'* - this is correct although you **don't** need to publish Play Games Services at this point.  When publishing your APK you will receive a warning to this effect and at this point you should 'publish anyway' - your Play Games achievements will stay in draft mode allowing you to delete/modify them until you're happy and ready to move to production, at which point you can also publish your Play Games Services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do **not** need to publish the game to the public to start testing achievements. Read this [link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub).

You'll upload an APK to the **Alpha** or **Beta** test phases on the Google Developers Console like any other. Once you've done that you will have to **whitelist** any testing accounts (their G+ accounts). That is also done on the Google Developers Console. Read the link above for how to whitelist accounts.

For resetting achievements read this [link](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#resetting_an_achievement).

Resetting achievements is also done through the Google Developers Console. The above link explains the process.

These are pretty simple processes and with those two links you should be able to answer both of your questions and hopefully any other ones you have!

Comment: Well, I must admit I'm still a bit confused... I've already whitelisted the email accounts of my friends. And so far, they have tested the game successfully by downloading the APK manually. But the Google Developer console says: _"The following groups can test your saved drafts for Google Play game services before they are published."_ But how do they actually access these saved drafts? Also, do I get to preview the Store Listing before I publish my app? Thanks.

Comment: @fluxi Manually? Do you mean you have sent them a .apk file or they have gone to the Play Store and downloaded it from there? When you publish an app, whether in Beta or Alpha, you have the ability to invite testers with their Google email address. They'll receive an email and a link to download your app from the official Play Store. The link is usually in the format of [https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.yourdomain.package](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.yourdomain.package). You can see what your app looks like in the store there and testers can download the app.

Comment: Yes, by manually I meant that I sent them the APK. Thanks for your time, everything seems to be quite clear now.

Comment: Well, except for one thing: the Google Play Games app does not show the "Achievements" tab at all for my game, although I have 5 achievements and everything _should_ be properly configured. All I have is "About" and "Players". Should I see the Achievements tab before publishing my game?